# Python Socket only sends after programm ends

Tags: python, sockets

I'm making a python programm which is supposed to send a string to a server made in java. My problem is that, while it manages to connect fine and send the command over, it only sends it after the socket has been closed or the programm ends.

Code:

```
import socket 

HOST = "IP" # IP here 
PORT = 8000 

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
print (socket.getaddrinfo(HOST,PORT)) 
print("sending") 
sock.sendall("[command]".encode()) # send Command 
print("send") 

while True:  
    data = sock.recv(1024) 
    print ('you recieved :' , data)
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997562/python-tcp-socket-why-sendall-message-is-sent-only-after-close) seems pretty relevant, I'd expect that you would have found that in a search though. Can you explain what you've researched so far and what your understanding of the problem is, so we don't waste our time telling you things you already know?

Comment: You program works perfectly as long as the server does not expect the client to send the command ending with a new line - which your client does not sent. So the problem is not the client, it is a different assumptions on how the messages are supposed to look in client and server.